# Get the post type - Wordpress menu - fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with the following code:

```
add_action('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_current_nav_class', 10, 2 );

function add_current_nav_class($classes, $item) {
    global $post;
        
    $current_post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type($post->ID));
    $current_post_type_slug = $current_post_type->rewrite['slug'];
            
    $menu_slug = strtolower(trim($item->url));
    if (strpos($menu_slug,$current_post_type_slug) !== false) {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "slug" in /.../functions.php:495

Can someone please let me know what is causing this error? And how to solve it :)

EDIT: Line 495 is the following:
`$current_post_type_slug = $current_post_type->rewrite['slug'];`

EDIT 2: If I downgrade to php 7.4, the error instead looks like this:
`Warning: Use of undefined constant slug - assumed 'slug' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /customers/1/0/9/mordenfelds.se/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/mordenfelds_2017/functions.php on line 495`

Comment: There is no constant used anywhere on that line. And if no constant gets used, it can't be an undefined one either.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The code was already in the original post. I added the image so it could be easier to see the line numbers and to show on which line the problem was.

I don't have a clue on how to solve this problem, and I don't know what to do to be able to give you pros any more info either... :/

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite part of the object is only accessible to custom post types, so every time its run on a page with the standard post types (post, page) its throwing the error. So modify the code to only run on a custom post type:

```
if ( 'YOUR_POST_TYPE' == get_post_type() ||  'YOUR_OTHER_POST_TYPE' == get_post_type())
```

So in your instance:

```
add_action('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_current_nav_class', 10, 2 );

function add_current_nav_class($classes, $item) {
    global $post;
    if( 'YOUR_POST_TYPE' == get_post_type($post->ID)){ 
        $current_post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type($post->ID));
        $current_post_type_slug = $current_post_type->rewrite['slug'];

        $menu_slug = strtolower(trim($item->url));
        if (strpos($menu_slug,$current_post_type_slug) !== false) {
            $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
        }
        return $classes;
    }
}
```